# SQL Server, local instance, No process is on the other end of the pipe

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

On a fresh installation, on my **local** SQL server instance, using SQL Server Management Studio, I can login with my Windows authentication, but not with my sa user. In both cases, I'm using `(local)` as my Server name. The error is the following:

```
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)
```

- The password is correct, since I've change it.
- I did reboot my computer since the installation of SQL Server.
- The **SQL Server Agent** is not running; I believe it's only for the jobs.
- The **SQL Server Browser** is not running; I believe it's only for remote connections, and it's not running as well on another computer where I don't experience the problem.
- In the SQL Server Configuration Manager, the SQL Native CLient (both 32 and 64 bits) enables Shared Memory, TCP/IP and Named Pipes (I didn't changed anything on these settings)
- In the SQL Server Configuration Manager, the SQL Server Network Configuration only allows Shared Memory and TCP/IP; Named Pipes and VIA are disabled (I didn't changed anything on these settings)
- In the SQL Server Configuration Manager, trying to activate the Named Pipes for the Network Configuration (and to restart the MSSQLSERVER service) didn't fixed the problem (I didn't reboot for this change).
- I've tried to change the connextion Server name from `(local)` to `192.168.x.x` or to `MY-COMPUTER-NETWORK-NAME` without any success.

I'm using `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)   Jun 17 2011 00:54:03   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)`.

Any ideas where to look or how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After double-checking the parameters I choose when reinstalling, I realized that **Mixed-mode** wasn't checked, only **Windows authentication mode**.

Following the instructions to this link fixed my problem: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx

(I'm quite impressed by the clarity of the Microsoft error message in this simple case)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was simply that I had misspelled the name of the database in the "Initial Catalog" part of the connection string.